# Getting Object moved in Jmeter response

Tags: jmeter, asp.net-ajax, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have recorded a script in Jmeter via HTTP script recorder but when i run the script i'm getting Object moved here error for on of the samplers of login transaction.
When search for the same request in the recorded xml i can see it has given a valid output.
Can someone tell me why when i'm running the script then only it is showing this error.
Please find below snapshots for reference.

1. Request from recording xml:
   [Recorded_Request_body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdMfs.jpg)
2. Request header from recording xml:
   [Recorded_Request_header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw1tj.jpg)
3. Request response from recording xml:
   [Recorded_Request_response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwgIm.jpg)
4. Request from script:
   [Script_Request_body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0WN4.jpg)
5. Header from script:
   [Script_Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUnip.jpg)
6. Response from script:
   [Script_Response_body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFkfe.jpg)

If its not clear from above images i can confirm that the request body and header from both the recording xml and script view tree are same.

Can someone help me to understand why i'm getting this object moved error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

In both requests you have identical `session` parameter:

[image]

and my expectation is that it should be different for different logins (even for the same user)

So inspect previous requests/responses, find where this `session` parameter value appears first time, extract it using a suitable JMeter's [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), store into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and replace this recorded hard-coded value with the variable.

More information: [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)

Comment: Ya i know its weird but these values are no where to be found in previous requests i have tried it.

Comment: Infact there are like 5-7 samplers in Login and all of them have these variable which are only found in those samplers only you cant co-relate them from recording and those all are working and giving expected output but only this request is not working